# converting vector to array in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question about converting from std::vector to an array.
I have a vector of pointers to object.  How can I convert it to an array of pointer to objects in C++?

The vector is 
`std::vector<pin*> *_PINS`

I want to convert it to
`pin** pins_arr`

I've tried everything that has been suggested in here but it doesn't work

I guess the reason why it's not working is because I have pointer to object as a type instead of basic type.

Would you please help me with this?  I've been stucked for the whole morning.

Thank you,

Comment: The way in which you are using this vector is completely wrong to begin with.  Storing a pointer to a vector is almost always wrong, as is using a pointer type as the template parameter.

Comment: Yep, doubtless you should try to eliminate pointers from the program entirely. Please tell us what went wrong with the existing suggestions. Also, if `_PINS->data()` doesn't work, try `& (*_PINS)[0]`, which is the C++03 version of the same thing.

Comment: Looks like nobody's mentioned yet that `_PINS` is an illegal identifier. It's better to avoid leading underscores, and (in my opinion) capitals in general. An underscore followed by a capital is reserved for the system, and the compiler might give you warning messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: if you really insist on doing a conversion like this, I suppose you could do something on this order:

```
std::vector<PIN *> *_PINS;

_PINS = new std::vector<PIN *>;

// make life a little easier:
std::vector<PIN *> tmp = *_PINS;

PIN *pins = new PIN *[10];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    pins[i] = tmp[i];

PIN **ppins = &pins;
```

I have to agree with Ed.S though -- what you're doing here defeats most of the purpose of using `std::vector` in the first place, and frankly strikes me as a bit silly.

Comment: Hi,I've tried this and it doesn't work. It gives me this error *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000000031 ***   Do you know why this is happening?  Thanks Jerry,

Comment: I think `_PINS->data()` would be more idiomatic in C++11.

Comment: You need to be aware that the returned pointer is only valid as long as the `vector` does not change. If you add or remove items, it might reallocate and invalidate your pointer.

Comment: Would you please show me the alternative way?  Thanks Thomas,

Comment: @ildjarn: There are many more projects on the previous version of C++ at this time.  Idiomatic or not, it's correct and is guaranteed to be, so what does it matter?

Comment: @Ed : It matters because the OP went out of their way to tag the question `c++11`, so demonstrating C++11 idioms (when they differ from C++03) should be a priority IMO. I never said the code shown is "wrong", just less idiomatic.

Comment: @ildjarn: Derp, so he did.  Touche :-D

Comment: Thanks for adding that edit.  The real problem here is how the vector is being used to begin with.

Comment: @EdS: it also matters when vector is empty, that's why C++11 added data() member.

Comment: @Eugene: That's a good point that I didn't consider.  Thanks, that's why I hang around here.  Always something to learn.

Comment: Hi, the reason is that I am a new C++ user. The second reason is that I have to make C++ to work with Perl XS and pointer object is the only way to go.  The reason why I use the vector of pointer is because of the usage models.  I was planning to have a shell which allow user to create pin and add it to the vector at a later time.  If you understand what I was trying to do and have another alternative, would you please show me?  I am more than willing to learn it.  I really need mentor right now in C++.  Thank you very much for all your responses and I am looking forward to your next response.

Comment: A vector is dynamic, so basically you get the user to enter whatever you need to make a PIN, and use that to create a PIN, which you push onto the vector.

Comment: Thanks Jerry,I will try what you suggested.  I have a question though, if the user creates the pin and add it at a later time to the vector, how vector is gonna guarantee that the pins will be stored in an optimized manner.  Will it reallocate the memory every time a pin is added to it?

Comment: @BinhVanPham: no -- it allocates a block of memory, and only when that gets full does it allocate a bigger block. The size increases geometrically which allows insertion with amortized constant complexity (if you don't understand that, I'd summarize as: "fast enough you rarely need to worry about it").

Comment: Thanks Jerry, now I understand the reason behind the suggestions above.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

the member function [data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)() returns the array, so _PINS->data() should work...

Answer (score 1):

So, first off; why are you using a vector of pointers at all? Why are you storing a pointer to a vector?!  This circumvents the vector's ability to manage memory for you and is almost certainly wrong.  Let the vector do what it was meant to do, it handles dynamic allocation and clanup for you behind the scenes.

vectors guarantee that their memory is stored in contiguous space, so the address of the first element can be used as a pointer, i.e., an array.  When you store a pointer to a vector you once again eliminate it's ability to clean up deterministically based upon scope.  The destructor will not run until you manually call `delete` on it.

You are essentially using a vector as an array here.  Again, this is wrong.  The vector itself is a lightweaght object, there is no good reason to dynamically allocate it.  Pass a `vector&` to functions that need to use it.

However, and more importantly; you are doing it wrong.  Just use this:

```
using std::vector;

//...

vector<pin> pins;  // that's it!  really!
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, I will try this as well.

Comment: Hi Ed, I can't really.  I want to create an aggregate (say class A), which contain a list of pointers to objects of another class (class B).  The reason I need to use pointers is because I don't want objects of class B to be destroyed when I destroy an object of class A.  However I need to be able to loop through the list of B objects if I want to.  I couldn't think of another way really.  Would you please help?

Comment: @BinhVanPham: Wow, still working on a problem from more than two years ago?  You have `std::shared_ptr` available to you.  However, it sounds to me like you may have a design problem on your hands.